# Attaching LED strips to bike

Tags: hybrid-bike, lighting

I'm interested in attaching LED strip(s) onto the frame of my bike. Are there features of LED strips that I should be looking for when making my decision of which one to get? What's the best way to attach them?

I plan to use the lights only from time to time, and would not mind having them battery powered (I would use rechargeable batteries anyways). In terms of colors, I would love to have the strip able to oscillate in patterns (most do in any case), though this is not necessary.

Comment: Tried to save it via edits to be less of a shopping question.

Comment: Double-sided foam tape is wonderful stuff, but will potentially damage your paint on removal.  White cable ties / zip ties might be best.

Comment: tried this on my kids bikes, best LED strips to look for are ones that run off small batteries otherwise you have to mess around wiring them up to work, or carry a large battery on the bike. If they're USB rechargeable that's even better. You can get them in multi colours and patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Sense this topic has re-opened i will submit an answer.

For custom frame lighting i believe it would be easiest to adapt a product that is already intended for use on bicycle frames or wheels such as what it seen below. It is a weather proof battery box wired to a silicone tube filled with chip LEDs, basically a rope light, the idea is the battery box attached to the hub, and the rope portion is woven through the spoke and centrifugal force with a little help from zip ties keeps it in place. 
[image]
They come in a variety of colors from a variety of manufacturers. Thus is why i think this would be the most simple and cost effective form to adapt. You could simple attach the battery box beneath the stem or any area out of the way and zip tie the rope where ever you want it on the frame. you could combine colors and get creative with it quite easily.

I know that the US distributor J&B sells them so most bike shops in the US should be able to get them, and ive seen them other places on the net as well. Their rather popular for customizing cruisers.

Heres a couple images of them installed:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The question was for frame lighting (as best I can interpret) but this is a nice answer for wheel lighting. I tend to prefer the spoke lights that rely on persistence of vision as they provide for a larger lit surface.

Comment: i was trying to imply that these would be quite easily adapted to be frame lighting, and would not require any heavy modification or custom wiring.

Answer (score -1):

I would argue for self-adhesive LEDS because they might have a more refined appearance, especially at day time. I would minimize the cable-ties and other fasteners for a cleaner look. Clean the bike well before adhering your fancy lights!

Comment: If adhesives did a good job of keeping thinks on bikes, we'd attach our cable housings and such that way.  When your adhesive comes loose and your rope lights tangle in your spokes, you'll probably end up wishing you had opted for a slightly less clean zip tie look.